# In a triangle ABC, D and E are points on AB and AC respectively such that DE ∥ BC. if AD = 2.4cm, AE=3.2cm, DE=2cm and BC=5cm, find BD and CE

Tags: geometry, triangles

I'm aware that the required values can be found using the concept of similarity of triangles ($ADE$ and $ABC$) but another requirement is that the question should be solved without using the concept of similarity in any step of the solution.
Kindly assist me in finding the required values $BD$ and $CE$.
This is a really urgent question.
Thank you

Comment: I don’t see how to solve this without considering proportion, which is a part of the geometric concept of similarity.  As a purely arithmetical exercise, perhaps, you can do without a figure and just work with the numbers, but it’s still the similarity of the triangles that justifies the numerical calculations.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the [intercept theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem)?

Comment: @Intelligentipauca yes.

Comment: @EdwardPorcella same thought...but I have to solve it without using similarity. Kindly help me with the artithmetic way if that's possible.

Comment: You can then solve your problem via the  intercept theorem, it is not difficult.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca could you guide me how to solve it using intercept theorem and WITHOUT the usage of Similarity of triangles. One thing I could figure out is , 2.4/DB = 3.2/EC. I cannot proceed further with this

Comment: Draw $FG\parallel AB$ such that $FC=AE=3.2$ and consequently $GC=2$. Apply i.t. to get $AF$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I request you to allow me to contact you to discuss this further as I am facing more problems while solvint.. Please provide me with a way to approach you. I need your help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{AC}{3.2}=\frac{AB}{2.4}=\frac{5}{2}$$Cross-multiplying,$$AC=\frac{5}{2}\cdot 3.2=8$$and$$AB=\frac{5}{2}\cdot 2.4=6$$So$$EC=AC-AE=8-3.2=4.8$$and$$DB=AB-AD=6-2.4=3.6$$But the first proportion above follows from similar triangles. Does the Intercept Theorem rest on an independent foundation?

Comment: I appreciate your efforts @EdwardPorcella but this is again similarity of triangles. Sorry but I do not get your last question.